# how to return none for names that don't match

Tags: python, regex

Use python to read the file regex_test.txt and print the last name on each line using regular expressions and groups (return None for names with no first and last name, or names that aren't properly capitalized)

Expected Output:

```
Abraham Lincoln
Andrew P Garfield
Connor Milliken
Jordan Alexander Williams
None (Madonna)
None (programming is cool)
```

```py
import re

with open("regex_test.txt")as names:
    
regex = names.readlines()

for name in regex:
    p1 = re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+[" "][A-Z][- a-zA-Z]+',name)
    
    if match:
        print(p1.group())
    else:
        print(None)
```

When I run it, I get all names excluding the last two but I am trying to get the outcome to print none for those two.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: if the match doesnt match it must print 1 ... or your indentation is off maybe ...

Comment: You provided the expected output, but what is the input for which that is the expected output? Can you include that example as well?

Answer (score 0):

2 major problems with your code -

##### 1. Indentation of `.readlines()` is wrong

this needs to be indented to be inside the `with` block, e.g.

```
with open("regex_test.txt")as names:
    regex = names.readlines()
```

##### 2. Undefined variable `match`

```
    p1 = re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+[" "][A-Z][- a-zA-Z]+',name)
    if match:
        # ^ this is not defined
```

Change this to `if p1:` and I think it works as you want, as best as I can tell

##### Fixed Version

`regex_text.txt` content (assuming this is what you have) -

```
Abraham Lincoln
Andrew P Garfield
Connor Milliken
Jordan Alexander Williams
Madonna
programming is cool
```

script with fixes described above -

```
import re

with open("regex_test.txt")as names:
    regex = names.readlines()

for name in regex:
    p1 = re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+[" "][A-Z][- a-zA-Z]+',name)
    if p1:
        print(p1.group())
    else:
        print(None)
```

output -

```
Abraham Lincoln
Andrew P Garfield
Connor Milliken
Jordan Alexander Williams
None
None
```